# Find the Number which does not contain the digit d

Tags: python

I need the numbers from 1-100 which does not having the digit 1 and 7, eg 0,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,22,23,24,25 so on. Below is the sample code to find the Number which contain the digit d. I need to modify according to my requirement.

```
def isDigitPresent(x, d): 

    # Breal loop if d is present as digit 
    while (x > 0): 

        if (x % 10 == d): 
            break

        x = x / 10


    # If loop broke 
    return (x > 0) 


# function to display the values 
def printNumbers(n, d): 

    # Check all numbers one by one 
    for i in range(0, n+1): 

        # checking for digit 
        if (i = d or  isDigitPresent(i, d)): 
            print(i,end=" ") 

# Driver code 
n = 500
d = 0
print("The number of values are") 
printNumbers(n, d)
```

Comment: Wait what's the question?

Comment: You have an error at line 23 ( `if (i = d or  isDigitPresent(i, d)): `) . Should be `==`

Comment: right, It should be like   ( if (i == d or isDigitPresent(i, d)): )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier if you convert the integer into a string and check just check if '7' or '1' are in the string. If not, print it.

```
def printNumbers(n): 
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        str_int = str(i)
        if not '7' in str_int and not '1' in str_int:
            print(i, end=" ")

# Driver code 
n = 500
print("The number of values are") 
printNumbers(n)
```

returns

> The number of values are
>   0 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 20 22 23 24 25 26 28 29 30 32 33 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that checks a digit individually.

```
def not_contain(num):
    nums = list(str(num))
    res = [i for i in nums if i not in ['1', '7']]
    return True if len(res) == len(nums) else False
```

Then use **filter()** to get the results you want.

```
mylist = [i for i in range(101)]
res = list(filter(not_contain, mylist))

# [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 ------, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's modifying your way to work:

```
def isDigitPresent(x, d):

    # Breal loop if d is present as digit
    while x > 0:
        if int(x % 10) in set(d):
            return True
        x //= 10
    return False


def printNumbers(n, d):

    # Check all numbers one by one
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        # checking for digit
        if not isDigitPresent(i, d):
            print(i, end=" ")


# Driver code
n = 500
d = [1, 7]
print("The number of values are")
printNumbers(n, d)
```